In which cases validation loss & validation f1 score both increase?
I'm training a image segmentation model using BCE loss. My validation loss is increasing but at same time my f1 score of validation is also increasing. What are all scenarios where it is possible?

Welcome to Cross Validated! Covertly, these two measures of performance refer to different models, with the binary crossentropy loss referring to the performance of the raw model predictions and the F1 score referring to the performance of the two-stage pipeline that takes the raw model predictions and then applies a classification rule to make discrete classifications, with a software default typically being to categorize as class 0 if the raw prediction is below 1/2 and as class 1 otherwise. Consequetly, this behavior you observe is not that weird.

@Dave which metric is more relevant in this case?

This post and the Frank Harrell blog posts referenced within are worth a read. My take on the matter is that estimating probabilities is the goal, not classification unless you have a handle on the misclassification costs. Do you have a handle on the misclassification costs?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
